# Finding the matching value after tokenizing in the Dictionary

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I have read a text file and converted to dictionary. And I have obtained the Keys of dictionary and made a list. I have opened another text file and I have tokenized it. I found the tokenized word in the keys also. But it is printing somewhere in the file i,e I want say first token has matching key to be printed first, next token matching value to be Printed next... But it is not printing in that manner.

```
import nltk
import codecs
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
f = codecs.open('bangaladict.txt', encoding='utf-8')

dictionary = {}
for line in f:
    line1 = line
    try:
        data = line1.split("\t")
        dictionary.update({data[0]: data[1].rstrip()})
    except:
        pass   
        dictionary_list=[]
        for y in dictionary.keys():
            dictionary_list.append(y)
        print(dictionary_list,"\t")

        with open('bengali.txt',encoding='utf-8') as fin:
            tokens = word_tokenize(fin.read())
        print(tokens)
        for i in dictionary_list:
            for a in tokens:
                if a.encode('utf-8') == i.encode('utf-8'):
                    print(i)
```

Please help.

Comment: ['text_000002', '``', 'শিল্পাঞ্চলে', 'ঢোকার', 'মুখে', ',', 'স্ন্যাক্সবারে', 'খাবার',   'কিনছিলেন', ',', 'বহুজাতিক', 'তথ্যপ্রযুক্তি', 'সংস্থার', 'কর্মী', ',', 'শুভময়',
পাশাপাশি
বহুজাতিক
খাবার
সংস্থার
ঘটিয়ে
শিল্পাঞ্চলে
কিনছিলেন
অনুশাসনের
অধ্যুষিত
কর্মী
মুখে
সরকার
বন্দ্যোপাধ্যায়
পুলিশকর্মীদের
শুভময়
মাওবাদী
বেতনবৃদ্ধি
চাইছে
তথ্যপ্রযুক্তি
ঝাড়খণ্ড
পাঠাতে
স্ন্যাক্সবারে
ঢোকার
এলাকায় Sample input and output

Comment: you question is not clear. It would be very helpful if you add an exmaple of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have two text files one text file contains bengali words and corresponding phonemes in english and other text file contains sentences bengali.For each word in second text file i want to find the corresponding phoneme in first text file. I am getting it but not in order of words after tokenization.

Comment: So you want to print the (key,value) pair if the key matches a token?

Comment: Yes.I am able to get both key and value of tokens but say not in the order of the words in the sentence.

Comment: Please edit your question, when you have additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I've understood what you wish to achieve. The reason why you're not getting the values in the order of the tokens is because of the way you've defined the loop structure.

Lets say the `dictionary_list` contains the values `[a, b, c, d, e]`. The `tokens` array contains the value `[e, i, y, a, b]`. 
When the outer loop executes, the value of `i` is `a`. The second loop checks through the tokens (which are in the order of sentence) and encounters `a` at `index = 3`, and hence, prints `a`.

But you wish to print `e` first since it occurs first in the token.

**Solution:** 
Swap the loop definitions

```
for a in tokens:
    for i in definitions:
        if a.encode('utf-8') == i.encode('utf-8'):
             print(i)
```

**OR**

```
for a in tokens:
    if a.encode('utf-8') in dictionary_list:
         print(a)
```

This way, the programs holds `e` from `tokens` first, if `e` exists in dictionary (which does exist), it prints `e`, and so on.

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: I changed the code. Now it is working fine.I have used OrderedDict from collections.thanks for the reply.